# Unable to Verify Cognito Token with Node

Tags: node.js, jwt, amazon-cognito

Cannot verify JWT Web-Token from Cognito.

Here the steps which I tried to do:

- Get a Token from the Cognito-Userpool Login Endpoint:
  https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000

from the result I then take the id_token part

- Retrieve the Keys from https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ap-east-1userpool/.well-known/jwks.json
- Trying to verify:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');

var token = <token_from_login_endpoint>;
var jwk = <key_object_which_matches_kid_from_token>;
var pem = jwkToPem(jwk);

var result = jwt.verify(token, pem, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, 
function(err, decodedToken) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(decodedToken);
});

console.log(result);
```

This results in an Error: name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'jwt malformed'

According to JWT.io the Token looks fine and has Header, Payload and the Public Key.

Comment: Why are you converting the token into pem

Comment: I don't convert the token into pem. But the public key. Like described in the docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

Comment: Do a `console.log(token)`? Is it malformed?

Comment: @Daniel, were you ever able to resolve this?